# PHP Script to convert .CSV files to .XML

Tags: php, xml, csv

Just wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of some tips / a script that will help me create an XML from an original CSV File, using PHP.

Cheers

Comment: I can. `*pointing in the google general direction with "convert .CSV  to .XML" request*`

Comment: Yeah the "software" that does it is really handy "Roll Eyes"

Comment: 'Just google it' Well gee if it was that easy don't you think Stu would have done it already?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is quite easy to do, just look at fgetcsv to read csv files and then DomDocument to write an xml file. This version uses the headers from the file as the keys of the xml document.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$inputFilename    = 'input.csv';
$outputFilename   = 'output.xml';

// Open csv to read
$inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
$doc  = new DomDocument();
$doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
$root = $doc->createElement('rows');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
{
    $container = $doc->createElement('row');
    foreach($headers as $i => $header)
    {
        $child = $doc->createElement($header);
        $child = $container->appendChild($child);
        $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
        $value = $child->appendChild($value);
    }

    $root->appendChild($container);
}

$strxml = $doc->saveXML();
$handle = fopen($outputFilename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $strxml);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Hi Michael I know this is an old post but I hope you notice this.  How can I nest this same function within itself?

What I have is client who wants XML > CSV > XML > CSV (conversion between the two) for their inventory system.  The items that their customers order are stored as such when converted from XML to CSV: item_name | item_price | item_quantity  What I do is have the CSV > XML create a temp csv to store this info.

All I want to do is exactly what this script does, again, with that temp file.  But for some reason it keeps trying to loop more than it should.  Please PM me if you can

Answer (score 6):

The code given above creates an XML document, but does not store it on any physical device. So replace `echo $doc->saveXML();` with

```
$strxml = $doc->saveXML();
$handle = fopen($outputFilename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $strxml);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 5):

[There are a number of sites out there that will do it for you](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=.csv%20to%20xml).

If this is going to be a regular process rather than a one-time thing it may be ideal to just parse the CSV and output the XML yourself:

```
$csv = file("path/to/csv.csv");

foreach($csv as $line)
{
    $data = explode(",", $line);
    echo "<xmltag>".$data[0]."</xmltag>";
    //etc...
}
```

Look up PHP's `file` and `string` functions.

Comment: Cheers Ben. A useful answer!! I'll have a look through. Been looking at fgetcsv on the PHP.net site too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bring up an old thread but I tried this script and I'm getting a DOM Exception error

The headers of our CSV Files are display_name office_number mobile_number and the error I'm receiving is DOMDocument->createElement('\xEF\xBB\xBFdisplay_name') #1 {main}

Comment: This is not an answer. You should try asking a new question. Provide the code, any changes you have made and describe the problems you are facing.