# using php to convert csv to xml for use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xml, csv

I am a newbie to scripting and am trying to use the following php code (taken from another post that was already answered: [PHP Script to convert .CSV files to .XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852796/php-script-to-convert-csv-files-to-xml), to convert csv data to xml (I named this file `csv2xml.php`).  I am trying to pull the outputted `xml` file that is created in the `php` script into javascript using the `DownloadURL` function so that I can parse the data further, but I'm not sure if I can use a php file in the `downloadURL` function in order to parse it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have to have this done by tomorrow so any help would be appreciated.  PHP code is first, followed by the section of javascript I am referring to.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$inputFilename    = 'input.csv';
$outputFilename   = 'output.xml';

// Open csv to read
$inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
$doc  = new DomDocument();
$doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
$root = $doc->createElement('rows');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
{
 $container = $doc->createElement('row');

 foreach ($headers as $i => $header)
 {
  $child = $doc->createElement($header);
  $child = $container->appendChild($child);
     $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
     $value = $child->appendChild($value);
 }

 $root->appendChild($container);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

---

```
downloadUrl("csv2xml.php", function(data) {
var xmlDoc = xmlParse(data);
var records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row");

...(parsing code)
```

Comment: it's much easier to parse CSV in JS than it is to parse XML

Comment: ... Aaaand to parse CSV in JS, check this nicely written function: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm

Comment: I'm trying to parse dynamic csv data such as this: time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag,magType,nst,gap,dmin,rms,net,id,updated,place,type
2014-10-28T14:02:15.520Z,37.4790001,-118.7878342,6.06,2.78,ml,27,72,0.1156,0.04,nc,nc72334366,2014-10-28T14:19:07.954Z,"24km SE of Mammoth Lakes, California",earthquake
2014-10-28T13:55:02.950Z,37.4806671,-118.7876663,6.93,2.62,md,21,141,0.1505,0.05,nc,nc72334346,2014-10-28T14:08:06.754Z,"25km SE of Mammoth Lakes, California",earthquake                                     I only want the data in positions 0-4, and 11-13

Comment: I only want the data in positions 0-4, and 11-13 & then use js w/ google maps api to map