# How do I convert a CSV file to XML using PHP script?

Tags: php, xml, csv

I am trying to convert my CSV file to XML. I am using this script below which I got from a post. But it's not working on my side. Any idea why I am getting this error?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$inputFilename    = 'test.csv';
$outputFilename   = 'test.xml';

// Open csv to read
$inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
$doc  = new DomDocument();
$doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
$root = $doc->createElement('rows');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
{
    $container = $doc->createElement('row');
    foreach($headers as $i => $header)
    {
       $child = $doc->createElement($header);
       $child = $container->appendChild($child);
       $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
       $value = $child->appendChild($value);
    }

    $root->appendChild($container);
 }

 $strxml = $doc->saveXML();
```

The error I am getting is here:

```
 Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error'
```

Here is my csv file:

```
  name, email, test
  john,john@foobar.com,blah
  mary,mary@blah.com,something
  jane,jan@something.com,blarg
  bob,bob@test.com,asdfsfd
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852796/php-script-to-convert-csv-files-to-xml

Comment: @MikeyBunny Yes, I am following that post. But it's not working on my side.

Comment: Can you include your CSV file, even the first few lines would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header row has spaces around the field names, spaces don't sit well with the names of XML elements.  Simply trim() the field names...

```
$child = $doc->createElement(trim($header));
```